# Default value for data type int is not getting set using JPA 1.9 (postgresql)

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using postgreSQL 9.3.1 , spring 4 and JPA 1.9 for my project. I need to set default value for one column in database using below JPA code. Also I have tried by passing datatype 'integer' and 'int' in Code. But still default value is not getting set. can any body suggest me what I am missing or any settings I need to do for JPA 1.9?

Thanks in advance.

@Column(name="cust_id",columnDefinition = "int default 0", nullable = false)

private int cust_Id=0;

Comment: There is no JPA 1.9. Also the default value is for an insert into the database, it will NOT set a default value in the field itself (only after reading it again from the database, the field will NOT be automatically updated).

Comment: In my project there is dependency in pom.xml " spring-data-jpa 1.9.0". While insert into database if i don't set value for cust_Id then Default value i.e 0 must be set in this cust_Id column, this happen for mysql. so please let me know why its not working with postgresql

Comment: You cannot not set a value, as it is a primitive it will always have a value, i.e. 0. Unless the field is in reality an `Integer` then it can be unset as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **@dynamic-insert** annotation, so Hibernate doesn’t include columns with null values.

Reference: https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-set-default-column-value-in-jpa/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30680304)

Comment: Okay, I will take care of that. I am new here, so will learn from the feedbacks :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. These review comments are left by community to increase quality of answers and overall content.